# Returning template_name + args in class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I had a function-based view with function:

```
def foo(request, id):
  args = {...}
  return render(request, 'template_name.html', args)
```

I would like to transform this into class-based code. Tell me please:

1. What View should I use (`TemplateView`)?
2. What method do I override (`render()`)?

Basically, question is: how the code above should look like using class-based approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `TemplateView` and override `get_context_data()` method:

```
class MyView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template_name.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'key1': 'value1'})
        return context
```

See also: [Adding extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).